# error: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found

Tags: flutter, dart

When I want to declare this function in my main.dart

```
class MapEqualColorMappingPage extends SampleView {
  const MapEqualColorMappingPage(Key key) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapEqualColorMappingPageState createState() =>
      _MapEqualColorMappingPageState();
}

class _MapEqualColorMappingPageState extends SampleViewState {
   List<_CountryTimeInGMT> _timeZones;
   MapShapeSource _mapSource;

...
}
```

i get the following error

error: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.

```
     '/map': (context) => MapEqualColorMappingPage(),  //The error is HERE
```

what should id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `MapEqualColorMappingPage(Key key)` write `MapEqualColorMappingPage({Key? key})`

```
class MapEqualColorMappingPage extends SampleView {

const MapEqualColorMappingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapEqualColorMappingPageState createState() =>
      _MapEqualColorMappingPageState();
}

class _MapEqualColorMappingPageState extends SampleViewState {
   List<_CountryTimeInGMT> _timeZones;
   MapShapeSource _mapSource;

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
const MapEqualColorMappingPage(Key key) : super(key: key);
```

you are stating that the constructor must have an argument of type `Key`, and here

```
'/map': (context) => MapEqualColorMappingPage()
```

you're trying to use the same constructor without any kind of argument.
You can:

- add a `Key` argument when you use the constructor
- remove the `Key` argument from the constructor declaration
- put the `Key` argument in the declaration in curly braces in order to make it optional

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing Key parameter.

const MapEqualColorMappingPage(Key? key) : super(key: key);

Mark it as optional Key?